# Optimal site allocation with accumulated cost and total number of sites minimisation

Tags: qgis, optimization, location-allocation

I am looking to define and solve the following GIS-based optimal location allocation problem. I have:

- A raster layer with the population living in each cell
- A friction layer (used to calculate accumulated cost, i.e. travel time, to a set of point features using for instance the SAGA accumulated cost tool or similar algorithms)

I would like to identify the optimal location (coordinates) of those point features, such that each population cell (i.e. cell of a raster layer) is at a maximum travel time of 60 minutes to the nearest site. We wish to do so by minimising the number of those point features.

I accept solutions in QGIS, PyQGIS, Python, and R. If it is not possible to achieve this with any of those tools, I can also consider other solutions, e.g. ArcGIS or other software.

Comment: Hi Jackk, I have exactly your same problem. Have you find a way to solve it? I've seen that in ArcGIS there are several guides to solve the location-allocation problem when a network dataset is available, but this generally comes in the form of a shapefile, and not a raster as the friction surface is.

Comment: Please have a look at the solution I found, which is described in the methods (also quoting the Github repo with the code to replicate it in R): https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.2009172117

Comment: Thanks a lot and many compliments for your work

Comment: Happy to help, thank you!